# Using JavaScript to validate form both onblur and when pressing submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onblur

I'm trying to validate fields in a form using JavaScript. The fields should be validated either when the user leaves a field (onblur) and when the user presses submit. The form should not be sent if the validation fails in any way on a required field.

The thing is I also have a JS function that if validation succeeds, should rewrite one of the fields that is validated, and send the form.

This is my HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./library/checkcreateuser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./library/hashcreateuser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="maindiv">
        <form name="createform" id="createform" onsubmit="return formhash();" action="#" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="checkEmail()" placeholder="E-postadress" maxlength="50" />
            <label for="email" id="labemail"></label><br />
            <input type="text" name="testemail" id="testemail" onblur="checkEmailConfirm()" placeholder="Bekräfta e-postadress" maxlength="50" /><br />
            <label for="testemail" id="labtestemail"></label><br />
            <br />
            ... other input fields that should be validated, not yet written ...
            <br />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Lösenord" maxlength="50" /><br />
            <label for="password" id="labpassword"></label><br />
            <input type="password" name="testpassword" id="testpassword" placeholder="Bekräfta lösenord" maxlength="50" /><br />
            <label for="testpassword" id="labtestpassword"></label><br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" placeholder="Registrera" onclick="validateForm()"><br />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my javascript for validation:

```
function checkEmail() {
    var validemail = true;

    var email = document.getElementById("email");

    var divided = email.split("@");

    var divlen = divided.length;

    if (divlen != 2) {
        validemail = false;
        document.getElementById("labemail").innerHTML = "Felaktig e-postadress";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("labemail").innerHTML = "<font color='#00cc00'>Korrekt epostadress</font>";
    }

    // More code to validate Email to come

    return validemail;
}

function checkEmailConfirm() {
    var validtestemail = true;

    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var testemail = document.getElementById("email");

    if (testemail != email) validtestemail = false;

    return validtestemail;
}


function validateForm() {
    var validform = true;
    var returnval = true;

    validform = checkEmail();
    if (validform == false) returnval = false;
    validform = checkEmailConfirm();
    if (validform == false) returnval = false;

    return returnval;
}
```

My problem is that nothing happens when i leave the email- or testemail-fields.

My second question is, if I want the form not submitted if any of the validations fails, but submitted and also hashed using the function called formhash() if the validations succeeds, is this the correct way?

---

EDIT: Using the Chrome debugger, i have the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function: checkcreateuser.js:9  
checkEmail: checkcreateuser.js:9  
onblur: newuser.php:16
```

Comment: I'll just put this here for consideration : http://jqueryvalidation.org/ - everything is better with jQuery.  As far as the problem, have you stepped through the javascript as it runs in a debugger?  That's generally step 1 in any javascript debugging process.

Comment: @JamesGaunt The problem is that I have never used jQuery, and very rarely JS, and I don't really have the time to learn jQuery since I have to be done with this tonight. As for debugging, no I havn't even thought of that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Code review, `validateForm` is a beast to read why not a one liner: `return (checkEmail() && checkEmailConfirm());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to check for the value entered in email and testemail you should use:

```
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var testemail = document.getElementById("testemail").value;// then use split on these values.
```

if you will use

```
var email = document.getElementById("email");//you will get error may be like split is not a function or something similar.
```